# Vertical responsive image (max-height) not working in Firefox

Tags: image, firefox, responsive-design, css

I'm looking for a way to set an image to the 100% height of the browser window (with a small padding at the bottom), centred on the page.

I've set up an example in codepen, which works great in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox, where the image shows at full size. What am I missing?

http://cdpn.io/sHJhl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.photo-bkg` also needs its `height` set:

```
.photo-bkg { height: 100%; }
```

[Here's a working fork of your pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdKfw).