# fluid images with max-height instead of max-width

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, fluid-images

So the classic way of doing fluid images is  with the max-width/height combo on the img css.

```
img { max-width:100%; height: auto;}
```

however I am in a situtation where I actually want the image to resize based on the containter's height limitation and not its width. I thought that a simple swap of properties would do the trick, but apparently it is not that simple. Check the fiddle bellow. If I set the container (wrap)'s width to a fixed pixel dimension, the image works as it should. However, if I change the img css to

```
img { max-height:100%; width: auto;}
```

and force a pixel height, nothing really happens.

jsfiddle: see updates bellow

Just to give you a little more insight of what I am trying to achieve. I will have a number of full-window containers one on top of each other. Each container should  take the whole window space. This is why I need the image to flex its dimensions depending on the container height (I am aware I may have to resort to jquery to force the container's height).

thanks for any insight

---

### update!

I have created two fiddles to better illustrate my ultimate goal.

I want to be able to stack containers that are each as tall as the whole window. Scaling the image up or down fluidly to help achieve this.

**fiddle1:** wrapper element is set to 100% width+height. if width is reduced, the image fluidly resizes.

http://jsfiddle.net/1geyww63/

**fiddle2:** wrapper element is set to a given pixel height. I would expect/imagine/cross my fingers that image would resize fluidly too fitting in all the content and the container's set height be respected. This however does not happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/1geyww63/4/

I hope I have made myself more understandable. I didn't want to throw too much information there. My main question remains how to make images resize fluidly with a height "centric" approach as opposed to the width.

[image]

Comment: here is a sample of what you need, hope this helps u http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdKfw, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251322/vertical-responsive-image-max-height-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: thanks @Aru, it is kind of that but not exactly. The example oddly allows the image to distort which I would like to avoid. and if can, I'd like to work with display: table for other reasons (but that may be wishful thinking in the end).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use positions.

You have to set wrapper for relative and img for absolute position:

http://goo.gl/n5CkRx simple example

Comment: once you start putting other elements around it it does not work.
it will only work if the image is the only element inside the container and its height is set in pixels/ems...

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q24j47tt/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/q24j47tt/2/). If this is what you want. Your question lacks some information. If you please elaborate the problem then we might be able to find the solution.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="hcenter">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/people" alt="">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus voluptas obcaecati consequuntur asperiores debitis. Corporis, dignissimos qui! Consequuntur ad, modi ex pariatur cupiditate optio recusandae dolores aperiam laudantium itaque aspernatur.
                    <br>More Lorem
                    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus voluptas obcaecati consequuntur asperiores debitis. Corporis, dignissimos qui! Consequuntur ad, modi ex pariatur cupiditate optio recusandae dolores aperiam laudantium itaque aspernatur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        img {
            /* img width responds to wrapper width*/
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }
        .wrapper {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .main{
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;

        }
        .footer {
            display: table-row;
        }
        .footer {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            height: 3em;
        }
        .main .content {
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .hcenter {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: thanks @abir_maiti, but it seems that on your example the image does not respond to a set height of the parent as well. Setting width AND height to both 100% will also allow images to distort which is not ideal. 
I have updated the post with two updated examples and will try to use display: block to see if it makes any difference (though the vertical alignment and footer positioning will be affected by doing that).
I will try